# Minify indented JSON string in .NET

Tags: .net, string, json, minify

I have an indented JSON string e.g.

```
{
  "a": 1
}
```

*However, I don't have the type of the instance to be serialized or deserialized.*

In my situation, what's the **most efficient way** to **minify** a JSON string? e.g.

```
{"a":1}
```

I don't mind using libraries if they are production-ready.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(myJSON, "(\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\")|\\s+", "$1")
```

should do it.  It makes sure that strings that contain space characters are preserved, and all other space characters are discarded.  All JSON keywords (`false`, `true`, `null`) have to be separated by commas or other punctuation so only white-space inside strings needs to be preserved.

---

The first option `(\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\")` matches a double quoted string.  The `(...)` mean that the output is captured and available in the replacement as `$1`.  The `[^\"\\\\]` matches any character except a double quote or escape character `\`.

Since matching occurs left-to-right, the second option, `\s+` will not match space inside a string.

So we match whole strings, and spaces outside strings.  In the former case, `$1` is the string token, and in the latter case `$1` is the empty string because group 1 was not used.

---

This works as intended because

1. the only tokens in JSON that can contain spaces are double-quoted strings.  There are no single-quoted strings or comments in JSON.
2. the JSON grammar requires single-character punctuation between all multi-character tokens, so removing space will not merge tokens.  In JavaScript, this could be problematic because space is required to break tokens; `var x=0` is different from `varx=0` and `x - -(y)` is different from `x--(y)`.

Comment: I find it more slightly more readable as a [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) `@"(""(?:[^""\\]|\\.)*"")|\s+"` - double quotation marks instead of quadruple slashes

Answer (score 3):

That regex below works for me.

```
string json = @"{ 
                  "window": {
                  "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
                  "name": "main_window",
                  "width": 500,
                  "height": 500
                  } 
                }"

Regex.Replace(json, @"\s(?=([^""]*""[^""]*"")*[^""]*$)", string.Empty);
```

I am using it on .NET Core app project. Regex is from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23860200/4492432).

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer provides the responder's solution to the OP's question/problem.