# Remove All Unnecessary Whitespaces from JSON String (in PHP)

Tags: php, regex, json, preg-replace, minify

How do I remove ALL **unnecessary** whitespaces from a JSON String (in PHP)?

I assume that I need to use preg_replace with some clever regex in order to NOT touch the whitespaces that are part of the values.

*A simple example would be:*

**Before:** '{ "key": "value with whitespaces to maintain" }'

**After:** '{"key":"value with whitespaces to maintain"}'

Basically, I'm looking for a way to minify and pack the string as tight as possible without changing any data.

Comment: One way would be to parse JSON and then use your own encoding implementation, it's not very difficult.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sorry to state the obvious:

```
$before = '{ "key": "value with whitespaces to maintain" }';
$after  = json_encode(json_decode($before));
```

And it actually matches perfectly your example, see `$after`:

```
{"key":"value with whitespaces to maintain"}
```

Comment: What if `$before` is array or object? Nested function calling doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @Lukas: Yes, given `$before` is not JSON Text but a PHP array or object value, there is no need to nest the function calls, as you only need to encode and not decode: `$after = json_encode($before);`. That's all, HTH.

Answer (score 5):

A PHP [preg_](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) solution:

```
preg_replace(
    '/\s(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/', ''
    , '{ "key": "value a with whitespaces to maintain" }'
);
```

Inspired by: [Regex to match all instances not inside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462578/alternative-to-regex-match-all-instances-not-inside-quotes)

Comment: very nice. I used it to cleanup qraphql queries before sending them to the API

Answer (score 0):

**PHP  =>**

Syntax : 
    `ltrim(string,charlist)`

Example :

```
`$str = '{ "name" : " Test Subject" }';`
`$obj = json_decode($str);`
`$obj->name = ltrim($obj->name);`
`var_dump($obj);`
```

**JS/jQuery =>**

Syntax : 
    `jQuery.trim( str )`

Example :

```
`var obj={ "name" : " Test Subject" };`
`console.log(obj);`
`obj["name"]=obj.name.trim(); // OR // obj.name.replace(/^\s+/,"");`
`console.log(obj);`
```