# How to add full title to modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, flickr

I've built a small web-app for my JavaScript class that goes above and beyond what is required, but while adding some extra features I ran into a bit of a hiccup.

I used what I believe is an older version of bootstraps lightbox by accident, but it works so I don't see any reason as to why use another version. Anyhow, when I try adding the title for the modal using data-title, I only get the first word of the title.

[image: image one]
[image: image two]

I've went ahead and made a clone of it on: http://flickrwebapp.netne.net/

Snippet for Naviego

```
        $.getJSON(flickrFetch, function(data) {
        $(data.items).each(function(index, value) {
            $('#photos').append("<h2>" + value.title + "</h2>");
            $('#photos').append('<img src=' + value.media.m + ' alt=photo data-title= ' + value.title + ' class="img-tumbnail img-resonsive" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="global-gallery" data-remote=' + value.media.m.replace('_m', '_b') + '>');
            $('#photos').append('<p><strong> Tags: </strong>' + value.tags + '</p>')
            clearInput();
        });

    });
```

Comment: As you are picking the <h4 class = "modal-title"> ¿??¿ </ h4>    ??????

Comment: I'm appending it to the <img> tag that I'm building for each object returned by the json from flickr. I'll add a snippet to my OP.

Answer (score 0):

[REMOVE WHITESPACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859713/remove-all-unnecessary-whitespaces-from-json-string-in-php)

That blank is killing you .. why not show you the correct title. Try Putting together all the words without spaces to see if it shows you everything. If you show it, you are close to solving the mystery :)

Comment: I don't believe I understand your answer. I removed the blank following 'data-title=' which is what I believe you suggested, but this did not help me any further.

Comment: removes the blanks within the modal-title, where you return the JSON string

Comment: ie using $.trim or .trim()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie =)